# ACE editor autocompletion remove local variables

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, ace-editor

I'm using ace editor and I've enabled basicautocompletion and I'm pulling data from another server to get the suggestions. Everything works fine, but I want to remove the local suggestions from the suggestion box.

Here is my relevant code:

```
var langTools = ace.require("ace/ext/language_tools");
var editor = ace.edit("editor");

editor.setTheme("ace/theme/xcode");
var TextMode = require("ace/mode/text").Mode;
editor.getSession().setUseWrapMode(true);

editor.setOptions({
  enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
});

var qtags = {
getCompletions: function(editor, session, pos, prefix, callback) {
  $.getJSON(jsonURL,
    function(tagList) {
      callback(null, tagList.map(function(qtag) {
        return {name: qtag.name, value: "#"+qtag.name+"() ", meta: "qtag"}
      }));
    })
  }
}
langTools.addCompleter(qtags);
```

Here is how it looks like:

[image: Example]

I've tried this line to remove all completers before adding my qtag completer, but that doesn't remove the local variables

```
langTools.completers = [];
```

Any input would be appreciated, I'm trying to avoid having to modify ace/ext/language_tools.js if possible, but at this point I'm open even to that option.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The trick is to call `langTools.setCompleters([])` **before** calling `editor.setOptions({enableBasicAutocompletion: true});`. May be its a good idea to set this option explicit to `false` before setting or adding the Completers. There is no need to change the sourcecode of the language_tools.

Example:

```
var langTools = ace.require("ace/ext/language_tools");
var editor = ace.edit("editor");

editor.setTheme("ace/theme/xcode");
var TextMode = require("ace/mode/text").Mode;
editor.getSession().setUseWrapMode(true);

var qtags = {
  getCompletions: function(editor, session, pos, prefix, callback) {
    $.getJSON(jsonURL,
      function(tagList) {
        callback(null, tagList.map(function(qtag) {
          return {name: qtag.name, value: "#"+qtag.name+"() ", meta: "qtag"}
      }));
    })
  }
}

langTools.setCompleters([qtags]);

editor.setOptions({
  enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
});
```

Answer (score 10):

you can use `langTools.setCompleters`

```
langTools = require("ace/ext/language_tools")
langTools.setCompleters([langTools.snippetCompleter, langTools.textCompleter])
```

or `editor.completers = [langTools.snippetCompleter, langTools.textCompleter, qtags]`

Comment: I've tried that, but what I need is only qtags, without the rest of them. In any case, still using the workaround solution by removing everything straight from the ace/ext/language_tools and then later adding just qtags in my own javascript as completer.

Comment: only qtags is even easier call `langTools.setCompleters([qtags])`, note that you need v1.1.8 for this to work.